# Have `projectile-find-file` fall back to `ido-find-file` outside of projects

Tags: projectile, ido

How can I bind <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> to invoke `projectile-find-file` when inside a project, and `ido-find-file` when not in a project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write your own command that checks:

```
(defun maybe-projectile-find-file ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively
   (if (projectile-project-p)
       #'projectile-find-file
       #'ido-find-file)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'maybe-projectile-find-file)
```